# Unpermitted parameter on triple nested form Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, strong-parameters

I have a triple nested form for the following models.

`roasts`, `countries`, `regions`

I can create a new roast, and it also creates the country, but not the region.  The console output:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cR5jRFbaslQU5+nWiU8rBWlC9OQ0E9zgMwY1YCF33Z1cwPkmJvsO5GKQ4hTNIB4Mku3EuL19WJTrg4e03gHW4Q==", "roast"=>{"roaster"=>"Square Mile", "name"=>"Red Brick", "countries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"country_name"=>"UK"}}, "regions"=>{"region_name"=>"Midlands"}, "bestfor"=>"", "roast"=>"", "tastingnotes"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Roast"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."user_id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: :regions
```

Somthing I notice is that for `countries` the log has "countries_attributes" but `regions` is just "regions" when this should also be regions_attributes.  I have the region params in the country controller nested within the country params.  Is that correct?  I have tried them not nested, and that doesn't work either:

My params:

```
def roast_params
  params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster, :name, :bestfor, :beans, :roast, :tastingnotes, :notes, :slug, :avatar, countries_attributes: [:country_id, :country_name, regions_attributes: [:id, :region_name]])
end
```

Changing this to `regions_attributes: [:region_id, :region_name]` doesn't help.

**roast.rb**

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tastings
  has_many :countries
  has_many :notes, through: :tastings
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries
```

**country.rb**

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, inverse_of: :country
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions
  belongs_to :roasts
```

**region.rb**

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, inverse_of: :regions
```

**roast controller**

```
  def new
    @roast = Roast.new
    @roast.countries.build.regions.build
  end
```

**form for nested fields**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.fields_for :countries do |countries_form| %>
      <%= countries_form.label :country %>
      <%= countries_form.text_field :country_name, class: "form-control" %>
<br />
      <%= form.fields_for :regions do |regions_form| %>
        <%= regions_form.label :region %>
        <%= regions_form.text_field :region_name, class: "form-control" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show some code from Model and Controllers?

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries` in the model for Roast?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Just updated post with models and controller

Comment: Could you add the form?

Comment: @Pablo just added the form fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
<%= form.fields_for :regions do |regions_form| %>
    <%= regions_form.label :region %>
    <%= regions_form.text_field :region_name, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Should be

```
<%= countries_form.fields_for :regions do |regions_form| %>
    <%= regions_form.label :region %>
    <%= regions_form.text_field :region_name, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```